# Wrap Div after every 3 iterations and count each divs inside

Tags: php, loops

Hey guys I have this code below that wraps the items after 3 iterations in a div however, I got confused on how to count the items inside that div as I'll refer to it as a condition for my custom class.

So for a visualization, it should look like this

projectrow projectitemcount-3

- project_item
- project_item
- project_item

projectrow projectitemcount-3

- project_item
- project_item
- project_item

projectrow projectitemcount-2

- project_item
- project_item

How do I approach this?

This is what I have come up so far

```
if( ($i % 3) == 0 ) { $griditemcounter = 1; }
                        
                        // If is the first post, third post etc.
                         ( ( $i % 3 ) == 0 ) ?  $html .= '<div class="project_row projectcount-'.$projectCounter.' grid-'.( ( $griditemcounter % 2 ) == 0 ? 'second' : 'first' ).'">'  :  $html .= '';                                  
                                $html .= '<div class="project_item grid'.$griditemcounter.'" style="background-image:url('.( $url ? $url : 'https://via.placeholder.com/940x1260').') ">';
                                    $html .= '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
                                        $html .= '<div class="project_item_img"><img src="'.( $url ? $url : 'https://via.placeholder.com/768x375').'" alt=""/></div>';
                                        $html .= '<div class="et_pb_text_inner project_item_content">';
                                            $html .= '<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>';

                                             $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy ); 
                                                foreach($terms as $term) {
                                                    $html .= '<p>'. $term->name. '</p>';
                                            }
                                        $html .= '</div>';
                                    $html .= '</a>';
                                $html .= '</div>';  

                        

                        ( $i == ( $post_count - 1 ) || ( ++$i % 3 ) == 0 )  ? $html .=  '</div>'  : $html .= ''; 
$griditemcounter++;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a variable called Count or Tracker and Set it to 1 outside of this loop. Once your code has iterated once and completed the process of doing this:

projectrow projectitemcount-(Add the variable Here)

- project_item
- project_item

Then you can add one to your variable outside of the loop. That way when the loop runs again it will add 2 onto the item count and add it onto the name.

Comment: Hi @amrik, thanks for responding however, I did try that before but the counter always resets to 1 which was weird.

it would go like  

projectrow projectitemcount-1  projectrow projectitemcount-1 projectrow projectitemcount-1

Comment: It sounds like it is being reset back to 0 before you have had a chance to give it to the name. You can keep an array of all the names as you go along or set the name just after the count has been incremented. It sounds like a logic error just have to be careful where the name is set and where the variables are incremented and set so they are not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Do the math beforehand: You got 8 items here, so integer-divide that by 3, that gives you 2, multiply by 3 again, gives you 6 - that is the number of elements you will put into "full" divs, that contain 3 items each.

So as long as your loop counter variable $i is < 6, you output 3 as your class suffix.

And after that, for the last div, you output 8 modulo 3, which is also 2 here in this instance, as suffix - that is the number of remaining elements that will go into the last container.

Quick & dirty example to illustrate the principle:

```
$data = range('A', 'H'); // array of fake data
$limit = 3;
$numberFull = floor(count($data) / $limit) * $limit;
$remainder = count($data) % $limit;

for($i=0, $l=count($data); $i<$l; ++$i) {
    echo $data[$i], ' - ',
       ($i % $limit == 0 ? ($i < $numberFull ? $limit : $remainder) : ''), "\n";
}
```

generates the following output:

```
A - 3
B - 
C - 
D - 3
E - 
F - 
G - 2
H -
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know the structure of your project items, but I will assume it is just a plain array like:

```php
$items = [
  ['name' => 'Project 1'],
  ['name' => 'Project 2'],
  ['name' => 'Project 3'],
  ['name' => 'Project 4'],
  ['name' => 'Project 5'],
  ['name' => 'Project 6'],
  ['name' => 'Project 7'],
  ['name' => 'Project 8'],
];
```

If you have the above structure, you can [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to get packs of at most 3 items then iterate over those pack to handle your display:

```php
<?php
$itemsChunks = array_chunk($items, 3);
?>
<?php foreach($itemsChunks as $itemsChunk): ?>
  <div class="project_row projectcount-<?= count($itemsChunk); ?>">
  <?php foreach($itemsChunk as $item): ?>
    <p><?= $item['name']; ?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which would then output:

```html
  <div class="project_row projectcount-3">
      <p>Project 1</p>
      <p>Project 2</p>
      <p>Project 3</p>
    </div>
  <div class="project_row projectcount-3">
      <p>Project 4</p>
      <p>Project 5</p>
      <p>Project 6</p>
    </div>
  <div class="project_row projectcount-2">
      <p>Project 7</p>
      <p>Project 8</p>
    </div>
```

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDLDoIwEEX3fMWEmAAJhii@Iq@FP@CeENKUmqICTQGNX48UisKiu5me6b1zh1HWdZofMcq0Vd6QooYAYg0gNkpUEAOCEIwrr@4EN7AxEluBtmrkqtFOjfZqdFCjoxqdBEo8mfJC2/IhsiLO0SfFojVHZINreVoUjleBW8UJwtRc/EM1zHrrDP04gJ/lL8BPVNeBzkbblFdvkDWu2rJZ@1EAQzVXtLxeQR80VKY/z8mtn2WhUBteZeRECPkO@0uRMpNqntzS6dec0i1p130B)